# Windows Phone Tiles Page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone development and i will like to create a page with buttons similar to the windows phone main page.

Something like this http://cdn.marketplaceimages.windowsphone.com/v8/images/b60e325c-ac45-4d7d-bdf9-f83762c23c90?imageType=ws_screenshot_large&rotation=0

Can you please suggest how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) (free) or T[elerik Rad Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) (not free)

Both of them have a "Hub Tile" Component that allows you to create "Live Tiles" like those inside your app.